# Apply a weight to a dataframe by date

Tags: python, pandas, functional-programming

I have a `DataFrame` that is `indexed` by `Date` and has a couple of `columns` like this:

```
                 XLY        UA
Date
2017-04-01  0.023991  0.060656
2017-05-01  0.010993 -0.081401
2017-06-01 -0.015596  0.130679
2017-07-01  0.019302 -0.101686
2017-08-01 -0.018608 -0.166207
2017-09-01  0.004684 -0.005298
2017-10-01  0.021203 -0.232357
2017-11-01  0.050658  0.034692
2017-12-01  0.021107  0.116513
2018-01-01  0.092411 -0.035285
2018-02-01 -0.034691  0.171206
...
2022-03-01  0.079468  0.039667
```

I have a `python` `dictionary` of weights

```
weights = {2022: 6, 2021: 5, 2020: 4, 2019: 3, 2018: 2, 2017: 1}
```

Is there a way to `apply` these weights to each `row` of the `Dataframe` so that for example, the `row` `2022-03-01` would be `0.079468 * 6` and `.039667 * 6` and so on for all the rows that are in the year 2022, when it gets to 2021, it would apply `5 *`, etc.

I know I can `loop` and do this. I am looking for a `functional` concise version.

Comment: Is index is a string or datetime?

Comment: index is a Datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mul` on `axis=0`:

```
weights = {2022: 6, 2021: 5, 2020: 4, 2019: 3, 2018: 2, 2017: 1}
cols = ['XLY', 'UA']
df[cols] = df[cols].mul(df.index.year.map(weights), axis=0)
print(df)

# Output
                 XLY        UA
Date                          
2017-04-01  0.023991  0.060656
2017-05-01  0.010993 -0.081401
2017-06-01 -0.015596  0.130679
2017-07-01  0.019302 -0.101686
2017-08-01 -0.018608 -0.166207
2017-09-01  0.004684 -0.005298
2017-10-01  0.021203 -0.232357
2017-11-01  0.050658  0.034692
2017-12-01  0.021107  0.116513
2018-01-01  0.184822 -0.070570
2018-02-01 -0.069382  0.342412
2022-03-01  0.476808  0.238002
```

Comment: see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71683805/apply-a-weight-to-a-dataframe-by-months-back

Answer (score 1):

I would do something llike this:

```
col_weights = np.array([weights[dt.year] for dt in df.index.get_level_values(0)])
df.loc[:, "XLY"] = df["XLY"] * col_weights
df.loc[:, "UA"] = df["UA"] * col_weights
```

fist line creates a weights array mapping index.year to weitghs dict.
next lines applies weight to each column.