# Apply a weight to a dataframe by months back

Tags: python, pandas, functional-programming

Using `pandas` version:

```
1.3.2
```

I have a `DataFrame` that is `indexed` by `Date` and has a couple of `columns` like this:

```
                 XLY        UA
Date
2017-04-01  0.023991  0.060656
2017-05-01  0.010993 -0.081401
2017-06-01 -0.015596  0.130679
2017-07-01  0.019302 -0.101686
2017-08-01 -0.018608 -0.166207
2017-09-01  0.004684 -0.005298
2017-10-01  0.021203 -0.232357
2017-11-01  0.050658  0.034692
2017-12-01  0.021107  0.116513
2018-01-01  0.092411 -0.035285
2018-02-01 -0.034691  0.171206
...
2022-03-01  0.079468  0.039667
```

I have a `python` `dictionary` of weights where the `tuple` (1,12) means 1 to 12 months back, apply that weight, and so on.

```
weights = {(0,12): 6, (13,24) : 5, (25,36): 4, (37,48): 3, (49,60): 2, (61, 72): 1, (72,83): 1}
```

Is there a way to `apply` these weights to each `row` of the `Dataframe` so that for example, the `row` `2022-03-01` would be `0.079468 * 6` and `.039667 * 6` and so on for all the rows that are 12 months from today, when it gets to 2021-03-01, it would apply `5 *`, etc.

The `index` is `Datetime`, not `string`.

I know I can `loop` and do this. I am looking for a `functional` concise version.

```
**Edit 1**

 bins = pd.to_datetime([today] + [today - pd.DateOffset(months = k[1]) for k in weights])
```

give error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "correlations.py", line 131, in <module>
    bins = pd.to_datetime([today] + [today - pd.DateOffset(k[1]) for k in weights])
 
 File "correlations.py", line 131, in <module>
bins = pd.to_datetime([today] + [today - pd.DateOffset(months = k[1]) for k in weights])


File "correlations.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    bins = pd.to_datetime([today] + [today - pd.DateOffset(months = k[1]) for k in weights])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
 idf:~/environments/python/yahoo_data$
```

Comment: What is the reference?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. I asked an almost identical question here if this help:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71682892/apply-a-weight-to-a-dataframe-by-date

Comment: @mozway. The reference is today if I understand what you ask.

Comment: Ah yes! The reference is from Today

Comment: @Ivan. Your dates are always the first day of a month, is it true for your real data?

Comment: Always first day of month, but if the solution did not assume that, it would be a big bonus

Comment: How should the "month" be handled, what is 2 months before 2022-02-28? And 2020-02-12?

Comment: If the rows date falls in between 1-12 months from today, apply that weight in the dictionary, if the date falls between 13-24 from today apply that weight in the dictionary...

Comment: The current month is 0 (no weight) or 1 (weight = 6)?

Comment: I just changed the first entry to be 0-12, although it really should be 0-11, but it's not important

Comment: You do not want to use `for` to check which range the month falls into, is that correct?

Comment: farsshad, I prefer not to use loops. But if you post that answer, I will uptick it just for effort. I am really looking for a map() type answer, but maybe I am asking too much

Comment: I guess one thing to do is to build a list of month/year that are 0-12, 13-24, etc with the corresponding weight, and then use  
Corralien answer in the comments above. In other words, unroll the dictionary.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. A month delta is ambiguous, which is why pandas doesn't handle it natively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
# Your dict
weights = {(0, 12): 6, (13, 24) : 5, (25, 36): 4, (37, 48): 3,
           (49,60): 2, (61, 72): 1, (72,83): 1}

# Today
today = pd.to_datetime('today').date()

# Create bins from today
bins= pd.to_datetime([today] + [today - pd.DateOffset(months=k[1]) for k in weights])

# bins must increase monotonically -> use [::-1] to reverse the list and labels
w = pd.cut(df.index, bins=bins[::-1], labels=list(weights.keys())[::-1]).map(weights)

# Answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682982/15239951
cols = ['XLY', 'UA']
df[cols] = df[cols].mul(w, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                 XLY        UA
Date                          
2017-04-01  0.047982  0.121312
2017-05-01  0.021986 -0.162802
2017-06-01 -0.031192  0.261358
2017-07-01  0.038604 -0.203372
2017-08-01 -0.037216 -0.332414
2017-09-01  0.009368 -0.010596
2017-10-01  0.042406 -0.464714
2017-11-01  0.101316  0.069384
2017-12-01  0.042214  0.233026
2018-01-01  0.184822 -0.070570
2018-02-01 -0.069382  0.342412
2022-03-01  0.476808  0.238002

>>> bins
DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-30', '2021-03-30', '2020-03-30', '2019-03-30',
               '2018-03-30', '2017-03-30', '2016-03-30', '2015-04-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

>>> w
Int64Index([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243488/discussion-on-answer-by-corralien-apply-a-weight-to-a-dataframe-by-months-back).

Answer (score 1):

This still uses a function which checks all the keys for determining the right weight.

Only full months are considered using `(now - row.name).days//30` where `row.name` is the index date. Change that if a month definition is different.

```py
def get_weight(month):
    weights = {(0,12): 6, (13,24) : 5, (25,36): 4, (37,48): 3, (49,60): 2, (61, 72): 1, (72,83): 1}
    for m, w in weights.items():
        if month in range(m[0], m[1]+1):
            return w

now = datetime.datetime.now()
df.apply(lambda row: row * get_weight((now - row.name).days//30), axis=1)
```

Or it is possible to create a map for unique month differences using the initial weights(to avoid repeating the calculation):

```py
all_monthes = (now - df.index).days//30

unique_months = all_months.unique()
weight_map = {}
for month in unique_months:
    weight_map[month] = get_weight(month)

df[['XLY', 'UA']] = df[['XLY', 'UA']].mul(all_months.map(weight_map), axis=0)
```

```
>>> df

              XLY          UA
Date        
2017-04-01  0.047982    0.121312
2017-05-01  0.021986    -0.162802
2017-06-01  -0.031192   0.261358
2017-07-01  0.038604    -0.203372
2017-08-01  -0.037216   -0.332414
2017-09-01  0.009368    -0.010596
2017-10-01  0.042406    -0.464714
2017-11-01  0.101316    0.069384
2017-12-01  0.042214    0.233026
2018-01-01  0.184822    -0.070570
2018-02-01  -0.069382   0.342412
2022-03-01  0.476808    0.238002

>>> weight_map
{60: 2, 59: 2, 58: 2, 57: 2, 56: 2, 55: 2, 54: 2, 53: 2, 52: 2, 51: 2, 50: 2, 1: 6}

>>> all_months
[60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 1]

>>> output

              XLY          UA
Date        
2017-04-01  0.095964    0.242624
2017-05-01  0.043972    -0.325604
2017-06-01  -0.062384   0.522716
2017-07-01  0.077208    -0.406744
2017-08-01  -0.074432   -0.664828
2017-09-01  0.018736    -0.021192
2017-10-01  0.084812    -0.929428
2017-11-01  0.202632    0.138768
2017-12-01  0.084428    0.466052
2018-01-01  0.369644    -0.141140
2018-02-01  -0.138764   0.684824
2022-03-01  2.860848    1.428012
```

Comment: Farshad elegant solution. It would be helpful if you gave the df output, imo

Comment: returns[[etf, ticker]] = returns[[etf, ticker]].mul(all_monthes.map(weight_map), axis=0)
 
ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 60: given 61

Comment: I added the output and weight map as well. Length of `all_monthes` should be same as `returns`. Check if that's correct. Also I edited `weights` to start from `0` (the first range), check that as well.

Comment: Ok  I see. But if the code for 2017 is to multiply by 1, how come your numbers are different from the original row?

Comment: 2017 is 30 months ago which is multiplied by 4.

Comment: 2017-04-01 is 60 months from today, 2022-03-30

Comment: 5 years times 12 months per year = 60 months ago

Comment: OMG! Why did I use 60 days for a month?! You are right, I corrected the code and the results. It uses 30 days for a month putting 2017 in multiplied by 2 range (60 months).